# Smoothness of a discrete time signal

Tags: continuity, piecewise-continuity

Is it possible to find the smoothness ($C^1$, $C^2$,... continuity) of a time sampled signal?

For a continuous function continuity can be found by the number of existing derivatives. When does the derivative for a discrete time signal exist?

Deriving a discrete signal using e.g. finte differences is always possible I guess and therefore I was wondering how to find the continuity of a discrete signal?

In Matlab I thought of using `dx = gradient(x)` multiple times until I get "large peaks" above a predefined threshold, which would make it possible to define some sort of "pseudo smoothness" for a discrete signal.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: For any sampled signal $x_n$ there exists a smooth function $f(t)$ such that $f(n) = x_n$

Comment: And what you need to know is the [Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) : in general, sampling a signal is a lossy process, but if it is band-limited and the sample-rate is high enough, we can reconstruct the original signal from the sampled signal.

Comment: And how to reconstruct the signal? Using interpolation? Is it also possible to fit a polynomal? Is polynomial fitting also some sort of interpolation? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using convolution. I don't know what you mean exactly with polynomial fitting. Try reading some courses and wikipedia about those topics.

Comment: So you would suggest finding a continuous function $f(t)$ using convolution and use this continuous function to check the smoothness?

Comment: @evolving, Hi, I also have the same problem. Is there any theory you found that we can use the finite difference to get the Smoothness of a discrete time signal?

Comment: @yuxuan I posted an answer to my question which I ended up using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the smoothness for discrete position (x,y) signals. After deriving these position values (which yielded acceleration a and [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions) $\kappa$),

\begin{equation}
\kappa(t) = \frac{\dot{x}(t) \ddot{y}(t) - \dot{y}(t) \ddot{x}(t)}{(\dot{x}(t)^2 + \dot{y}(t)^2)^{3/2}}
\end{equation}

I ended up using the following smoothness measures which were suitable in my case:

**The histogram of a (zero mean) signal** can be used to identify the amount the signal changes and to locate its mean value. For example, the acceleration of a vehicle can be assumed constant with a mean of zero. If a driver accelerates or brakes, the result is a changing acceleration, which is indicated by the histogram in the form of bins located in a region around the mean. Signals with high amplitudes result in histograms with widely spread bin locations and show that the driver's manipulation of the accelerator or steering wheel changed abruptly. Because such abrupt changes are rare in everyday driving, the result of the histogram analysis is a distribution with an average value near zero and a specific standard deviation after fitting a Gaussian or normal distribution.

**The norm of a changing signal** is another method, apart from the the histogram evaluation approach, which indicates how frequently a signal changes. After deriving the position twice (=acceleration), the norm is relatively small if the signal is close to a zero-mean white noise signal, and large otherwise. This metric is utilized by comparing the norm of a reference signal to the derivatives of the signal your interested in.

**The cross-correlation** is used as a measure of similarity between the reference signal and the signal your interested in. Specifically, it helps to find time delays, or lags, between two signals. For example, when a reference signal $x_n$ is cross-correlated with another signal $y_n$ using equation,

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:crosscorrelation}
 \hat{R}_{xy}(m) =
 \begin{cases} 
  \hfill \sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1} x_{n+m}y_{n}   \hfill & m \geq 0 \\
  \hfill \hat{R}_{xy}(-m) \hfill & m<0 \\
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

cross-correlation values $\hat{R}_{xy}(m)$ are obtained, which indicate the correlation at lag positions $m$. Larger values in magnitude mean stronger correlation whereas values near zero show less correlation. For signals that are of the same length and have equal sampling time, the lag position $m$ of the maximum value $\hat{R}_{xy}(m)$ indicates where in time the signals are most similar. If the cross-correlation has its maximum at lag $m = 0$ the signals are not delayed and can be assumed similar. Cross-correlation can be performed between signals with different lengths, but it is essential to ensure that they have identical sampling.

However, using the cross-correlation did not brought very good results because of the noisy signals. I would go with the histogram method or the norm. Hope this helps.

Ref https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/measuring-signal-similarities.html.